# simple html dom returns weird results with some URLs

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I'm using simple HTML DOM and I'm getting weird results when using it on some sites.

Here is the HTML output it produces from [this link](http://www.kmart.com/shc/s/p_10151_10104_09535015000P?prdNo=1&blockNo=1&blockType=G1)

```
����������������
```

I checked the sources and it's a mess.

It also hangs whenever I try to use it [on this site](http://www.bedbathandbeyond.com/default.asp?) Again, the HTML is a mess.

Any ideas?

EDIT: Code block added:

The `$str` variable below is defined earlier in my code within a CURL request.

I'm using a CURL request to

```
$html = str_get_html($str);
$images = array();
if($html !='') {
    foreach($html->find('img') as $element) {
        if(strtolower(substr($element->src, -4)) != '.gif') {
            $images[] = url_to_absolute($baseURL, $element->src);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are we supposed to help you, if we don't know what are you doing with the side. Link works fine in my browser...

Comment: @ldiqual Code block added above

Comment: @PiTheNumber Of course the links work, that's not the problem. Simple HTML DOM is returning weird HTML results FROM those links.

Comment: @PiTheNumber what do you mean "what are you doing with the side"?

Comment: ahhh, [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) is a parser. I thought it is something from you. Makes more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

� always looks like an encoding problem.

Maybe [utf8_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php) / utf8_encode can help.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem to, but is not was charset the problem was gzip compresion that simple html dom don't handle Here is my solution
[Simple html dom character encoding issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550903/simple-html-dom-character-encoding-issue/11125728#11125728)