# Character Encoding issue with PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, mysql, dom, curl, simple-html-dom

I am using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser `http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/` to fetch data like Page Title, Meta Description and Meta Tags from other domains and then insert it into database.

But I have some issues with encoding. The problem is that I do not get correct characters from those website which is not in English Language.

Below is the code:

```
<?php
require 'init.php';

$curl = new curl();
$html = new simple_html_dom();

$page = $_GET['page'];

$curl_output = $curl->getPage($page);

$html->load($curl_output['content']);
$meta_title = $html->find('title', 0)->innertext;

print $meta_title . "<hr />";

// print $html->plaintext . "<hr />";
?>
```

Output for `facebook.com`page

`Welcome to Facebook â€” Log in, sign up or learn more`

Output for `amazon.cn`page

`äºšé©¬é€Š-ç½‘ä¸Šè´­ç‰©å•†åŸŽï¼šè¦ç½‘è´­, å°±æ¥Z.cn!`

Output for `mail.ru`page

`Mail.Ru: Ð¿Ð¾Ñ‡Ñ‚Ð°, Ð¿Ð¾Ð¸ÑÐº Ð² Ð¸Ð½Ñ‚ÐµÑ€Ð½ÐµÑ‚Ðµ, Ð½Ð¾Ð²Ð¾ÑÑ‚Ð¸, Ð¸Ð³Ñ€Ñ‹, Ñ€Ð°Ð·Ð²Ð»ÐµÑ‡ÐµÐ½Ð¸Ñ`

So, the characters is not being encoded properly.

Can anyone help me how to solve this issue so that I can add correct data into my database.

Comment: What happens if you switch the encoding in your browser under View > Encoding to something else?

Comment: If I switch browser encoding to UTF-8, it works.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550903/simple-html-dom-character-encoding-issue

Answer (score 10, accepted):

@deceze and @Shakti thanks for your help.

+1 for the article link posted by deceze ([Handling Unicode Front to Back in a Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)) and it also worth reading [Understanding encoding](http://kunststube.net/encoding)

After reading your comments, answer and of course those two articles, I finally solved my issue.

I have listed the steps I did so far to solve this issue:

1. Added `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` on the top of my init.php file,
2. Changed CHARACTER SET of my database table field which is storing those value to UTF-8,
3. Set MySQL connection charset to UTF-8 `mysql_set_charset('utf8', $connection_link_id);`
4. Used htmlentities() function to convert characters `$meta_title = htmlentities(trim($meta_title_raw), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');`

Now the issue seems to be solved, BUT I still have to do following thing to solve this issue in FULL.

1. Get the encoded charset from the source `$source_charset`.
2. Change the encoding of the string into UTF-8 if it is already not in the same encoding. For this the only available PHP function is `iconv()`. Example: `iconv($source_charset, "UTF-8", $meta_title_raw);`

For getting `$source_charset` I probably have to use some tricks or multi checking. Like checking headers and meta tag etc. I found a good answer at [Detect encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910793/detect-encoding-and-make-everything-utf-8)

Let me know if there are any improvements or any fault on my steps above.

Answer (score 2):

> If I switch browser encoding to UTF-8, it works.

So you're simply not setting the correct HTTP header to designate your document to be UTF-8 encoded and the browser is interpreting it in some other encoding. Use:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: The PHP code listed above is just for the purpose of testing which works if I add the content type header. My real code will add the info (value of `$meta_title`) to the database then another page will retrive those value from database, but at that page it is not working even I set to UTF-8.

Comment: @Prakash: You must ensure that the database current connection is set to accept `utf-8` data. Run this query `SET NAMES UTF-8` before sending any query to database and also make sure that your database, table, column are set to utf-8 encoding. Then setting UTF-8 header in your another page should work.

Comment: @Prakash Then I recommend you read [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Romanian characters. Nothing worked until I used

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-2');
```

ISO-8859-2 being the character set for Eastern European letters. So find the right character set for your language and use it in header.